# :Key on v-for to rerender a row in the list || composite values as :key rather than index

Tags: vue.js, v-for

Recently, I came across an issue, to fix which i need to give a Unique value for `:key` in my `v-for`. But the problem is that i don't have a unique value .and giving the index as `:key` does not solve my problem. My Array for `v-for` is a list of objects, with an object being

> `{sourceValue:"1",targetValue:"2",assigned:true}`

And my unique value will be combination of sourceValue and targetValue... So how should i define the `:key` on the `v-for` ? Is `:key="cfg.sourceValue+cfg.targetValue"` Okay? how can i verify the key value on DOM?

```
 v-for="(cfg, idCfg) in $store.state.configurations" :config="cfg" :key="idCfg"
```

[image]

Comment: Use vue-devtools to inspect it. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools. Additionally, why do you think giving index is not enough?

Comment: Shouldn't `idCfg` be unique? The second argument in a `v-for` binding is the index.

Comment: @Terry thank you ! i have been using index and that does not work in my case. The issue that i am trying to fix is When i uncheck the last column in the above table from first row,that row is removed in the array by means of a XHR response. Then the next record in the list is displayed as unchecked (while its actually a checked record) ....happening because that first row is not rerenderd as per my understanding)

Comment: I think this is an XY problem: what you want is that each row should be a subcomponent on its own, where it will store/track its own checkbox state. In this way, you will not cause checkbox state resets when removing rows from your table.

Comment: @Terry..Its already a component on its own `config-record` and the real code is `</div>
                <config-record v-for="(cfg, idCfg) in $store.state.configurations" :config="cfg"  :key="cfg"></config-record>
    <div>`

Comment: checkbox state is also not reset in my case. the checkbox's model value is `TRUE` still it remain unchecked because the view is not rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the two values concatenated by `+` really worked for me.

> `<config-record v-for="(cfg, idCfg) in $store.state.configurations" :config="cfg"  :key="cfg.sourceValue+cfg.targetValue"></config-record>`

I have verified it in Vue Dev tools to see that the :key value is infact unique and concatenated values of both sourceVal and targetVal.

> $store.state.configurations = [
> {sourceValue:"TestDivya",targetValue:"3",assigned:true},{sourceValue:"TestDivya1",targetValue:"test",assigned:true},{sourceValue:"DEBUG_LOGGING",targetValue:"ENABLED",assigned:true}
> ]

[image]